# SciFi novel concerning future (this year) and music broadcast from star system

Tags: story-identification, books

- **Publication:** I would wager a guess at around 1970.
- **Plot Points:** It is set in the year 2019 and a program to detect extra-terrestrial life hears music broadcasts from a star system. They go to the planet where the music is being broadcasted from. Unfortunately, only one of the crew members lived to the year 2075 to tell the story of the expedition. Other than that, I don’t remember much...
- **Author:** I don’t actually remember who the author is, but I combed through huge lists of Asimov’s, Bradbury’s, and Orwell’s works to find this book, but I could not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you are thinking of [*The Sparrow*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sparrow_(novel)) by Mary Doria Russel. Publication is a little later than you suggested (1996), but the plot points you remember match pretty well. The story is told non-linearly, mostly from the perspective of Emilio Sanchez, linguist and Jesuit missionary, who is one of a small group dispatched to a distant planet after he and some others detect music being broadcast from space.

We learn pretty early in the book that Sanchez is the only survivor—most of the story is figuring out out he got to that point.